# Flutter - create scrollable ListView with scrollbar to the right of all children

Tags: flutter, listview, scrollbar

I have an iOS/android flutter applist of widgets like a date range picker with a 2 month view that respond themselves to touch.

I tried to add a scrollbar to help the user scroll more easily up and down the list, but the scrollbar overlaps with the date picker. One pixel off, and you change the date instead of scrolling.

I would like a scrollbar that is to the right of all my widgets, so that the touch areas are clearly separate. Check out this stackoverflow screen as a visual reference. Scrollbar and body don't overlap

My abridged code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset : true,
    body: Scrollbar(
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      thickness: 25.0,
      radius:Radius.circular(5.0),
      controller: _scrollController,
      child: ListView(
      controller: _arrowsController,
      children: [
      Text('Some text'),
      SizedBox(height:10.0,),
      collapsingCalendarWidget // contains a dateview picker and other goodies
    ],
   )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

default `ScrollBar` widget isn't draggable, but you can check [draggable_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar) package

Comment: Same issue. The scroll bar covers some of the content, and I cannot add a SizedBox to the right of every item as a dummy buffer.